# Can I leave these strapping pins floating?

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, pcb-design, esp32

I am using the ESP32-C3-WROOM micro-controller. I am about to create my final pcb design for this project of mine. Currently, I am using the strapping pins to put the MC into download boot mode or SPI boot mode. In my final design, I plan on having the MC programmed before placing on my board (I don't want to be able to re-program board). With that being said, can I leave the strapping pins floating since I won't need to program my ESP32?

Datasheet: https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-c3-wroom-02_datasheet_en.pdf

- Page 12 has information on stapping

Answer (score 2):

In my design, I never leave any input pins floating (unless the datasheet tells me to) because they can create unexpected behavior (can induce noise, makes unpredictable reboots, etc). If you have a good reason not to tie them, I would at least place a resistor footprint to either tie it up or down if you have any issue.

If by software you can drive them, then yeah, floating will work. If they are for boot purpose, I would not take that chance. Hope this helps!